# Calculating means in replicates using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from an experiment in the following form, where each experiment and treatment has been run in duplicate and the hits are the genes associated with a specific event:

```
experiment  treatment   replicate   hit
1   1   1   gene1
1   1   1   gene2
1   1   1   gene1
1   1   1   gene1
1   1   2   gene1
1   1   2   gene1
1   2   1   gene1
1   2   1   gene2
1   2   2   gene2
1   2   2   gene2
```

What I want to do is calculate the mean count of each gene within a treatment.

I can get to the counts of the genes per experiment using `value_counts()`:

```
counts = df['hit'].groupby([df['experiment'], df['treatment'],
                            df['replicate']]
                          ).value_counts().unstack()
```

which produces output like:

```
experiment  treatment   replicate    gene1  gene2
1   1   1   3   1
1   1   2   2   NA
1   2   1   1   1
1   2   2   NA  2
```

But what I really want is the mean counts per treatment, so (assuming replacement of NA with 0):

```
experiment  treatment   gene1   gene2
1   1   2.5 0.5
1   2   0.5 1.5
```

Any ideas? Applying `.mean()` to the value_counts seems to work out the mean across all columns, rather than each replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the table you have and do another groupby:

```
>>> g = d.hit.groupby([d.experiment, d.treatment, d.replicate]).value_counts().unstack().reset_index()
>>> print g
   experiment  treatment  replicate  gene1  gene2
0           1          1          1      3      1
1           1          1          2      2    NaN
2           1          2          1      1      1
3           1          2          2    NaN      2
>>> print g.fillna(0).groupby(['experiment', 'treatment']).mean()
                      replicate  gene1  gene2
experiment treatment                         
1          1                1.5    2.5    0.5
           2                1.5    0.5    1.5
```

You get an extra meaningless column that is the mean of the replicate numbers, but you can just throw that out.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'm guessing that if the replicate column used A, B rather than 1,2 then the mean() function would ignore it as non-valid and you wouldn't get the extra column.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the underrated `pd.get_dummies` :

```
In [31]: pd.get_dummies(df.hit)
Out[31]:
   gene1  gene2
0      1      0
1      0      1
2      1      0
3      1      0
4      1      0
5      1      0
6      1      0
7      0      1
8      0      1
9      0      1

In [32]: df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.hit).groupby([df.experiment,df.treatment,df.replicate]).sum(); df2
Out[32]:
                                gene1  gene2
experiment treatment replicate
1          1         1              3      1
                     2              2      0
           2         1              1      1
                     2              0      2

In [34]: df2.groupby(level='treatment').mean()
Out[34]:
           gene1  gene2
treatment
1            2.5    0.5
2            0.5    1.5
```